# Complex-valued branches of the Lambert W function

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, reference-request, lambert-w

$\require{begingroup} \begingroup$
$\def\e{\mathrm{e}}\def\W{\operatorname{W}}\def\Wp{\operatorname{W_0}}\def\Wm{\operatorname{W_{-1}}}$

\begin{align} 
\W_n\left((4n-1)\,\tfrac{\pi}2\right)
+\W_{-n}\left((4n-1)\,\tfrac{\pi}2\right)
&=0
\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
\W_{n-1}(-(4n-3)\,\tfrac\pi2)
+\W_{-n}(-(4n-3)\,\tfrac\pi2)
&=0
\tag{2}\label{2}
,\\
\int_0^{(4n-1)\tfrac{\pi}2}
-\tfrac12\,(\W_n(x)+\W_{-n}(x))\, dx
&=(4n-1)\tfrac{\pi}2
\tag{3}\label{3}
,\\
\int_0^{(4n-3)\tfrac{\pi}2}
-\tfrac12\,(\W_{n-1}(-x)+\W_{-n}(-x))\, dx
&=(4n-3)\tfrac{\pi}2
\tag{4}\label{4}
,\\
\int_0^1
-\tfrac12\left(\W_n(\tfrac\pi2\,(4n-1)\,t)
+\W_{-n}(\tfrac\pi2\,(4n-1)\,t)\right)\, dt
&=1
\tag{5}\label{5}
,\\
\int_0^1
-\tfrac12\left(\W_{n-1}(-\tfrac\pi2\,(4n-3)\,t)
+\W_{-n}(-\tfrac\pi2\,(4n-3)\,t)\right)\, dt
&=1
\tag{6}\label{6}
\end{align}

for $n>1$, where $\W_{n}$ is a complex-valued branch
of the Lambert $\W$ function.

Question: is there known references where these expressions are mentioned?

$\endgroup$